# improving performance of rails view rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, redis, scalability

I have an E-Commerce Rails Application where we need to output Orders placed by Customers on a page within last one year for reporting reasons. Now, the data set is quite large and displaying these Orders on a single page takes quite a bit of SQL processing. This task initially was very slow and hence I moved all the required order details to a Redis Server and fetching of data has become really fast now but we are still not quite there.

Here's what we have:

```
Rendered **path**/sales_orders.html.haml within layouts/admin (39421.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44925ms (Views: 39406.8ms | ActiveRecord: 417.2ms)
```

The application is hosted on Heroku and if a request takes more than 30s it is killed. As you can see we are well above that limit. Most of the time is lost in rendering the view.

The page contains a date filter where the user gets to choose what Date Range to select the Orders from. So, caching is not the ideal solution since Date Ranges might change every time.

Any ideas how this can be done?

The Redis keys are of the format (The following is a Redis Hash):

```
orders:2012-01-01:123
orders:yyyy-mm-dd:$order-id
```

User simply provides a Date range and I get all the keys within that date range under the orders namespace.

Here's how I would get the Customer Name for instance from the Redis order key:

```
= REDIS.hget(order_key, "customer_name")
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, one of the acceptance criteria is to not use Pagination

Comment: Well if the criteria is not to use pagination then the criteria is for it not to work.  For a view to take 44s to render, there must be a massive amount of data being shown on it.  This will be hard on the client too as their browser will have to render a giant page.  Could you let us know how many records we are talking about here on this page?  Also what does your view code look like?  I just think that you can't expect an arbitrary large query to always display fast with no pagination or limits.

Comment: @MichaelPapile I totally agree with you. Some non-tech people just put weird and hard to achieve criteria. I've been trying to educate the stakeholders on what's involved here.

there are about 12,000 records on the page and my Safari and Firefox browsers go semi-unresponsive when the page is rendered. You are right!

Comment: @JasdeepSingh  Yes, letting non-tech people know what is hard or easy is the hardest task in tech!

Comment: I realize this is long since past due, but for something like this it seems like you might do well to render the initially viewable portion and then use javascript to render the other pages of data on the screen after initial page load. Not ideal but it would at least break the request up into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider building the report with a periodic task using the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) addon.
As long as last-minute orders are not required to be included in the report, you can build your reports nightly and have them available for immediate download to read with your morning coffee, or even have them mailed to you (or whoever needs to read them.)

If you need interactive selection of periods for reports, you will need to queue the requests up and build the reports using [background jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

Comment: Yeah +1 the best thing would be to pre-render these documents if at all possible

Answer (score 2):

Almost all your time is spent in rendering views. That probably means you have a lot of partials or other complex view logic. Some of your options are:

1. Paginate your output, but offer a PDF or CSV for unpaginated output.
2. Simplify your view logic...a lot.
3. Try a helper like cycle instead of rendering complex tables or nested partials.
4. Move your rendering into the client with JSON and JavaScript.

That's about it, really. If one or more of those don't get you where you need to go, it may be time to revisit your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use fragment caching. Reading a fragment is very fast (~0.5 ms) and in my experience you'll see a huge speedup gain by not re-rendering your partials again and again. It's also a fairly cheap solution as Rails takes care of invalidating the fragments (if you use the model as part of the cache key) and it requires minimal changes in your template. I.e. the solution could be as simple as:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <% cache ["v1", order] do %>
    <%= render order %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```